# Extract two fields by line with multiple separators

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this

```
field01 field02 field03 field04 definition: field05; measure: field06; weight: field07;
field11 field12 field13 field14 definition: field15; measure: field16; 
field21 field22 field33 definition: field25; weight: field27;
field31 field32 field03 field34 definition: field35; measure: field36; wight: field47;
```

the desired output is the second field and the field after 'definition:

```
field02 field05
field12 field15
field22 field25
field32 field35
```

The separator involves ' ','definition:' and ';'

the most I have done is

```
awk -F'definition:' '{print $2}' file |awk 'split($1, a, ");") {print substr(a[1],-5)}'
```

It gives me:

```
field05;
field15;
field25;
field35;
```

But it's not what I want. field05,field15 and field35 can be of different length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this awk:

```
awk '
{  
    split($0,temp,"definition: ") #Get everything after "definition: " in temp[2]
    split(temp[2],final,";")      #Get everything between "definition :" and ";" in final[1]
    print $2,final[1]
}'
```

One liner, as requested:

```
awk '{split($0,t,"definition: ");split(t[2],f,";");print $2,f[1]}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. How can convert it in one liner?

Comment: @EmilioGalarraga Done. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hacky proposal:

```
awk -F'[:;]' '{ print $2,$1 }' file | awk -F' ' '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

Output

```
field01 field05
field11 field15
field21 field25
field31 field35
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the show but another `awk` solution just for fun

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '{f=3; while ($f!~"defin") f++; print $2, $(f+1)}' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the field separator is a regular expression, so this works as an example:

```
awk -F ' definition: |; measure: |; weight: |; wight: |[ :;]+' '{NF=NF};1' file

field01 field02 field03 field04 field05 field06 field07 
field11 field12 field13 field14 field15 field16 
field21 field22 field33 field25 field27 
field31 field32 field03 field34 field35 field36 field47
```

I am pretty sure that wight on the last line is an error, but I included it to show the flexibility of the idea.

But given that all you need are fields 2 and 5. And that the number of field is not stable, we need to do two splits to get field 5, and one more for field 2. The first split breaks the line at `definition:`, the trailing part is split on the other delimiters to get the **first** field (which is always what you call field5 (the first after `definition`). The last split on `[ ;:]` is done to get the second field:

```
awk '{split($0,a," definition: "); split(a[2],b,"[ :;]");
      split($0,a,"[ ;:]");
      print a[2],b[1]}
    ' file

field02 field05
field12 field15
field22 field25
field32 field35
```

Comment: weight in lines 1 and 4 are not errors. And I need the field 2 and the field after 'definition:' not exactly field 5. As you can see on line 3, I omitted field 4 but that must have been the following after 'definition:'.

Comment: @EmilioGalarraga Emilio the code is doing exactly what you descrbe. Where is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command and it worked fine

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /definition:/){gsub(";","",$(i+1));print $2,$(i+1)}}}' filename
```

output

```
field02 field05
field12 field15
field22 field25
field32 field35
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as a separate answer just because it is an alternative way of looking at the problem and I like it.... Not saying it's good practice. I just liked the alternation.... I think it's pretty.

```
sed "s/definition: /\n/" file1 | awk -F'[ ;]' '{printf $(NR%2+1)((NR%2==0)?"\n":" ")}'
```